# JPQL row_number() analog

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

Sorry if the title is not clear, I will try to describe the problem in more details - there are two tables, let it be `students` and `books`, each of students can have many books. I'm trying to write JPQL query which would pick all the students and only one book for each of them (doesn't matter which one until the results are consistent between two queries). In Oracle I'd use `row_number() ...` and then took only the books where it is = 1. Is there a way to do something similar in JPQL? (or probably easier as I'm not sure that my sql way is optimal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure SQL namely `HAVING`, `GROUP BY`, and `MAX`.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE books (book_id INT UNSIGNED, stud_id INT UNSIGNED);

INSERT INTO books VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(4,4),
(5,5),
(6,6),
(7,7),
(8,8),
(9,1),
(10,2),
(11,1),
(12,2),
(13,3),
(14,4),
(15,5);

SELECT stud_id, max(book_id) FROM books GROUP BY stud_id HAVING max(book_id);
```

I reduced your problem to a single table. Also, I chose `MAX` to return only one book_id per student--the greatest-- which is consistent between two queries. Unless you provide us with some meaningful sample data, you have to figure out how to apply this stuff to your problem yourself. Hope I could help :)